# How to combine 4 sql queries into a single query with good performance?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem to solve. First I split this problem into parts and so I wrote four queries separately but now I need to put them together as if it were a single call to return a single result. How can I do this?

**1) I select purchases according to branch and store**

```
SELECT CD_PURCHASE FROM TB_PURCHASE_STORE WHERE CD_BRANCH = ? AND CD_STORE = ?
```

**2) I validate if the promotional period of the purchase is within the current date (today)**

```
SELECT CD_PURCHASE, DT_BEGIN_PROMOTION, DT_END_PROMOTION FROM TB_PURCHASE 
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(DT_BEGIN_PROMOTION) AND TO_DATE(DT_END_PROMOTION)
```

**3) From the purchase code, I check which products are active**

```
SELECT CD_PURCHASE, CD_PRODUCT FROM TB_PURCHASE_PRODUCT WHERE FL_ACTIVE = 1
```

**4) Finally, I return some fields according to the customer id**

```
SELECT CD_PURCHASE, CD_PRODUCT, ID_CUSTOMER, DT_LAST_PURCHASE 
FROM TB_PURCHASE_SALES WHERE ID_CUSTOMER = ?
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do would all help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to make a query that provides a list of records composed of: purchase code, product code, customer id and date of last purchase. To return this data, I need to consider a few things: only purchases released by the branch and store (first step), only purchases that the promotional period range is within the current date (second step), only purchases that have active products (third step ), only purchases made by the customer who arrives in the requisition (step four)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried below query? I've assumed you want INNER JOIN for all the tables, and CD_PURCHASE is common link in all the tables, and CD_PRODUCT is the link between TB_PURCHASE_PRODUCT and TB_PURCHASE_SALES.

```
SELECT TPS.CD_PURCHASE,
TP.CD_PURCHASE, TP.DT_BEGIN_PROMOTION, TP.DT_END_PROMOTION, 
TPP.CD_PURCHASE, TPP.CD_PRODUCT,
TPSS.CD_PURCHASE, TPSS.CD_PRODUCT, TPSS.ID_CUSTOMER, TPSS.DT_LAST_PURCHASE
FROM TB_PURCHASE_STORE TPS, 
TB_PURCHASE TP, 
TB_PURCHASE_PRODUCT TPP,
TB_PURCHASE_SALES TPSS
WHERE TPS.CD_BRANCH = ? AND TPS.CD_STORE = ?
AND TPS.CD_PURCHASE = TP.CD_PURCHASE
AND SYSDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(TP.DT_BEGIN_PROMOTION) AND TO_DATE(TP.DT_END_PROMOTION)
AND TPP.CD_PURCHASE = TPS.CD_PURCHASE
AND TPP.FL_ACTIVE = 1
AND TPSS.CD_PURCHASE = TPS.CD_PURCHASE AND TPSS.CD_PRODUCT = TPP.CD_PRODUCT
AND TPSS.ID_CUSTOMER = ?
```